# Gimp Plugin Mixing Images

Tags: plugins, gimp

[image]Hi. I have a qustion about a gimp plugin and where, if, I can find it.

As you can see, in the image bellow there is a printed image. On one side the printed image is normal, on the other it it's mixed. Can I find a plugin that can mix a image like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the PythonFu [Slice](http://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html) filter. It will take an image and then divide it into however many pieces you want in as a even a way as possible, then you can manually re-join them in whatever way you want.

There's also the [Guillotine](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-guillotine.html) plug-in that divides up the image based on any guides on the image. Again, this would require you to manually composite the images back together.

And, finally, there's this [Split and join images](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26331) filter I found on the GIMP Registry. I haven't got it to work, but perhaps you can. It also seems to be partially in another language.

These aren't exactly what you want, as it's not automatic - but perhaps you can take these and create your own PythonFu script or GIMP extension!

Comment: I have installed this script: "Split and join images"; it's now here: http://gimper.net/resources/split-and-join-images.627/; but, I can't understand how to make it work. Is there a "Help" for it, somewhere?